# Facebook Android-SDK Posting Message Issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to post a message to the users wall using the official facebook SDK for Android.

```
            parameters.putString("method", "feed");
            parameters.putString("link", "www.example.com");
            parameters.putString("name", "Example Web");
            parameters.putString("description", "An example website for testing.
            parameters.putString("message", etMessage.getText().toString());
            facebook.dialog(this, "feed", parameters,
                    new DialogListener() {...
```

Everything gets successfully addressed in the Dialog, except for the message.  In the dialog, the message field is empty.

Please help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BK said, the message field is now deprecated. The only way I've found that you can still do this it to request the publish_stream permission and make a post directly to their wall, without letting them see the message or click "Share" (from the Facebook UI). In some cases this could be what you want though. It was for me. [This tutorial](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/) was helpful in showing how to do that.

Additional note: You can create a custom dialog to let the user view or edit the message prior to posting.

Answer (score 4):

The message field was deprecated in July 2011 because Facebook wants users to post unique content. See this [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/):

> **Breaking Change: "message" parameter ignored in Feed Dialog**
>
> On July 12, we are ignoring the message parameter in Feed Dialogs.
>   This eliminates the ability to pre-fill stream stories (prohibited by
>   Policy IV.2). This change encourages users to share authentic and
>   relevant content with their friends.

Comment: Wow...that sucks...Any other way to do it?

Comment: You can build your own dialog, prompt for publish_stream permission and then post directly to their wall.

Comment: I do have my own dialog, but I'm not sure how to proceed with your recommendation...Could you please show me how to do it manually?